EG25-G show unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00 when connected to linux
I have raspberry pi 4 and EG25-G modem when ubuntu 20 server is running on it. when I connect modem to raspberry pi and do ifconfig following show for EG25-G. how can i fix it
wwan0: flags=4240<POINTOPOINT,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

